# Excel SUMPRODUCT "greater if" #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having an issue when using the SUMPRODUCT function to reference tables with "greater than" and "less than" in SUMIFS values. More specifically, the following gives me a "#VALUE!" error.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Perf_Data[Gross Claims Paid (non-cumulative)],Perf_Data[Year (AY/UWY)],"<"&'OUTPUT - S.19.01'!$A24,Perf_Data[Development Year],">="&Perf_Data[Year (AY/UWY)]+15,Perf_Data[Applicable Line of Business],LoB_Selection),Perf_Data[@[Currency check and multiplier]])
```

The code above sums the gross claims paid, if their AY/UWY year is lower than a specific year X, the development year is higher than the year X + 15, and they follow a specific line of business. These gross claims paid should then be multiplied by their currency multiplier - and this is where Excel starts throwing out the value error.

The Perf_Data table has data in all the rows filled out (= the ranges are the same size) and my formula works well (= no errors) if the years are specified exactly (no greater/lower than), as follows:

```
SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Perf_Data[Gross Claims Paid (non-cumulative)],Perf_Data[Year (AY/UWY)],'OUTPUT - S.19.01'!$A27,Perf_Data[Development Year],SUM('OUTPUT - S.19.01'!$A27,'OUTPUT - S.19.01'!C$21),Perf_Data[Applicable Line of Business],LoB_Selection),Perf_Data[@[Currency check and multiplier]])
```

(the code above sums gross claims paid according to a specific AY/UWY and development year, line of business

*The two common causes - different size of arrays, numbers in text format - are not present.* Any ideas on how to fix this?

Any constructive replies are MORE than welcome!

Comment: Perhaps the [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can help you in this case (if you are on XL2010 or greater). Its very powerful and has the ability to ignore errors.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you for an idea. AGGREGATE seems to be powerful indeed. I am unsure on its application to my issue, however; more precisely, how to use it to multiply the SUMIFS number with the appropriate currency multiplier. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to circumvent this issue altogether by using only sumproduct with " --(logical test)" syntax. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, so others know how you solved it. Will be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested (thanks for the reminder @ScottHoltzman !), I'm posting my solution.

Since the SUMIFS solution didn't work, I turned to SUMPRODUCT as my solution. I found it used in older workbooks, made when SUMIFS didn't exist yet, it was commonly used because of its multiple-criteria possibility (which I'm sure many of you remember).

Not many parameters changed; I just went from this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Perf_Data[Gross Claims Paid (non-cumulative)],Perf_Data[Year (AY/UWY)],"<"&'OUTPUT - S.19.01'!$A24,Perf_Data[Development Year],">="&Perf_Data[Year (AY/UWY)]+15,Perf_Data[Applicable Line of Business],LoB_Selection),Perf_Data[@[Currency check and multiplier]])
```

to this:

```
=SUMPRODUCTPerf_Data[Gross Claims Paid (non-cumulative)],--(Perf_Data[Year (AY/UWY)]<'OUTPUT - S.19.01'!$A24),--(Perf_Data[Development Year]>=Perf_Data[Year (AY/UWY)]+15),--(Perf_Data[Applicable Line of Business]=LoB_Selection),Perf_Data[@[Currency check and multiplier]])
```

The conditions turned into logical checks; for all the values in the column where the condition isn't met, that row is multiplied by zero (that's what the "--" is for - it turns "FALSE" boolean into "0", and "TRUE" into "1". Therefore, the value column is multiplied by 1 in the appropriate (= passed logic check) rows (which does not change them), and in the end multiplied by the currency multiplier to get the desired value.

As a side note, while the other formula "=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Perf_Data[Gross Claims Paid (non-cumulative)],Perf_Data[Year (AY/UWY)],'OUTPUT - S.19.01'!$A27,Perf_Data[Development Year],SUM('OUTPUT - S.19.01'!$A27,'OUTPUT - S.19.01'!C$21),Perf_Data[Applicable Line of Business],LoB_Selection),Perf_Data[@[Currency check and multiplier]])" worked, it led to incorrect numbers. My guess is that the information provided by the SUMIFS formula wasn't pairing with the Currency check and multiplier properly, so I ended up turning it into SUMPRODUCT the same way as described above.

Let me know if you have any questions!